# CMD command to write few characters at the beginning of a video file

Tags: linux, windows-7, script, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I have a video file, saying a mp4 file, I want to add few characters at the beginning of the file making the file cannot be played. how can I do this on Windows 7?

**EDIT:**

how about commands in Linux, such as dd command? I can use Linux to do this if necessary, adding few characters in and then removing them when needed.

Comment: There is no internal command for that. better option is to change the extension of the file and then explicitly open the file with any media player.

Comment: I know how to change the extension but I think it is better to corrupt the file and then restore it later.

Comment: If the intended purpose is protect the file against unauthorized playback, it may be worth trying to just encrypt it with a password. Many compressors do this (without compressing anything).

Comment: I want to corrupt and uncorrupt many files very quickly. encrypt it is a way to go but cannot do it in one batch action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Warning:

#### You cannot easily undo this using `CMD.exe` or any other simple Windows tools.

---

To do, as you have actually asked, *add a few characters*, you can use the Windows `copy` command.

First, use Notepad, or some other editor, to create a file with *a few characters* in it. Perhaps it could be "Don't Play This!". Of course, just one space, or any other character, would be enough. Save the file using a name you want, say `NoPlay.txt`.

The command `COPY /b NoPlay.txt+MyVideo.mp4 LockedVideo.mp4` will create the new file `LockedVideo.mp4` by combining the two files `NoPlay.txt` and `MyVideo.mp4`. The `/b` tells copy to use binary mode, so it will not try to do anything to the files other than *copy* them. (Change the names to suit your files.)

Now the new file will be a "corrupted" video file, the player will detect that, and fail to play the file. It may not even recognize it as a video file at all.

---

As stated in the warning at the top, using Windows commands the reversal of the "corruption" is not simple. Probably not even possible with commands directly. A hex editor could be used to fix it, but that's not exactly a smooth workflow.

Using Linux, however, to reverse the corruption is almost trivial.

Taking the sample given above: `Don't Play This!`, there are 16 characters. How, and where, the file is created can change how real size of that file. Whether or not the file has an <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end, and if it has Windows or Linux line endings matters.

In Windows, and Linux, the directory listing (`DIR` or `ls -l`) will show the real size, and you need to know that for unlocking the file. On Linux, using the `echo` command to create the file makes it 17 bytes in size. With the known *exact* size of the file you use replacing the `17` in the command below, you can unlock the video. I'll stick to using the same file names as used in the corruption process above. The obvious use of `dd` *will* work, but you won't like the speed.

```
dd if=dd if=LockedVideo.mp4 of=MyVideo.mp4 bs=1 skip=17
```

The reason for the options is that `skip` is the number of blocks to skip. With the default block size of 512 bytes it would remove too much, even with `skip=1`. Setting the block size to one, `bs=1`, you have complete control over the number of bytes skipped. The downside is that `dd` will read one block, write one block, repeat. For a 1.5 GB file, that's going to take a very long time. `dd` has a work around for this, `iflag=skip_bytes` meaning that the skip value is bytes, not blocks. With that option you can still control the number of bytes dropped, but use a larger block size. (Videos are often involved with DVDs so a block size of 4K seems reasonable.)

```
dd if=LockedVideo.mp4 of=MyVideo.mp4 bs=4096 iflag=skip_bytes skip=17
```

---

### A Different, All-Linux, Approach

If, as the edit to the question suggest, you're willing to use Linux for the process both ways, the whole process becomes a bit simpler, as no file is needed for the "corruption". There are two options, depending on how pressed your storage is for space. Near as I can tell there's no significant difference in speed between the options.

One option is to pad the beginning of the video file with random bytes of a full block size. A reasonable block size could be 4096, same as used for ISO files anyway.

The second option is to add a single byte to the beginning of the file. That should be enough to make it non-playable, and take the least additional space for the new file.

Option 1, full block of random bytes:

```
# Corrupting the video file
dd if=/dev/random of=LockedVideo.mkv bs=4096 count=1
dd if=MyVideo.mp4 of=LockedVideo.mp4 bs=4096 conv=notrunc seek=1
# Cleaning the video file for playing
dd if=LockedVideo.mp4 of=MyNewVideo.mp4 bs=4096 skip=1
```

Option 2, single byte added to beginning

```
# Corrupting the video file
dd if=MyVideo.mp4 of=LockedVideo.mp4 bs=4096 oflag=seek_bytes seek=1
# Cleaning the video file for playing
dd if=LockedVideo.mp4 of=MyNewVideo.mp4 bs=4096 iflag=skip_bytes skip=1
```

---

#### Last word

There is a very old implementation of [`dd` for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) (Win32 environment), which may, or may not, be usable now. The options and workings "appear" to match the ancient Linux version, i.e.: no `iflag=skip_bytes`, but the full block option above should work, if the program works. YMMV, however.

Comment: how about use Linux command to corrupt it and then restore it back?

Comment: Of course the number of characters is very important, including end-of-line marker from the "text" file, but for five characters you could use `sed 's/^.\{5\}//' LockedVideo.mp4`, which would, probably, uncorrupt, without renaming, LockedVideo.mp4

Comment: @ user686699 then how to restore MyVideo.mp4? I know I can use Linux split command. any counterpart in windows?

Comment: The new edit information should handle all the rest of your questions, and needs.